# Constants in cherrypy configuration file

Tags: python, configuration, constants, cherrypy

I have a following Cherrypy configuration file:

```
[/tmp]
tools.staticdir.on: True
tools.staticdir.dir: "../something/path/"
```

Is it possible to put the string `"../something/path/`" as a constant in this file and use it something like that: `tools.staticdir.dir:MY_PATH_CONST` ? If it is possible, how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Add an identifier to your config file...

```
[custompath]
path : "../something/path/"
```

then access the path in your code this way:

```
cherrypy.request.app.config['custompath']['path']
```

Hope this helps.

Andrew